# Modifying call arguments of multiple methods in class

Tags: python, methods, arguments

I have a class, that has (too) many methods. Most of the methods take an argument (always the same name) - I need to change the type of the parameter to something else, but want to also accept the "old" version of the parameter (and `raise` a `DeprecationWarning`).

**EDIT**: *We can assume that the argument is always passed as keyword argument.*

What is the most **DRY** way of doing this?

The first solution that springs to my mind is something like:

```
def check_orc(orc):
    if isinstance(Snaga, orc):
        orc = convert_to_urukhai(orc)
        raise DeprecationWarning("You should not be sending snaga to combat")
    return orc

class Warrior():
    def slash_orc(sword, shield, opponent):
       opponent = check_orc(opponent)
       ...

    def hack_orc(warhammer, opponent):
       opponent = check_orc(opponent)
       ...
```

Comment: add the most used parameter to self, that way you would avoid passing it all the methods

Comment: or, you can *hardly* edit your souce code by sed command. this is not DRY, but more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I don't understand - how can I add the parameter to `self` when it is an external entity to the instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

avasal's comment is correct. For educational purposes however, here is a decorator implementation of what you want:

```
from functools import wraps

def convert_orc(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, opponent, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(Snaga, orc):
            raise DeprecationWarning(...)
            return f(self, convert_to_urukhai(opponent), *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return f(self, opponent, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Warrior():
    @convert_orc
    def slash_orc(self, opponent, sword, shield):
       ...

    @convert_orc
    def hack_orc(self, opponent, warhammer):
       ...
```

*Note: I moved `opponent` to the first position in the parameters*

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell if this is always the last parameter? If not, you'll have to work with its name.

My idea would be to do this:

```
def check_orc(orc):
    if isinstance(orc, int):
        orc = str(orc)
        print DeprecationWarning("You should not be sending snaga to combat")
    return orc

def check_opp(meth):
    code = meth.func_code
    argnames = code.co_varnames[:code.co_argcount]
    if 'opponent' in argnames:
        from functools import wraps
        argidx = argnames.index('opponent')
        @wraps(meth)
        def replace(*a, **k):
            if 'opponent' in k:
                k['opponent'] = check_orc(k['opponent'])
            else:
                a = list(a)
                a[argidx] = check_orc(a[argidx])
                a = tuple(a)
            return meth(*a, **k)
        return replace
    else:
        return meth

class Warrior():
    @check_opp
    def slash_orc(self, sword, shield, opponent):
       print "slash", (sword, shield, opponent)

    @check_opp
    def hack_orc(self, warhammer, opponent):
       print "hack", (warhammer, opponent)

Warrior().slash_orc(1,3,4)
Warrior().hack_orc(6,5)
Warrior().slash_orc(1,3,opponent=4)
Warrior().hack_orc(6,opponent=5)
Warrior().slash_orc(1,3,"4")
Warrior().hack_orc(6,"5")
Warrior().slash_orc(1,3,opponent="4")
Warrior().hack_orc(6,opponent="5")
```

It is quite an ugly hack, but nevertheless should work and saves you from reordering your parameters.

Here I use a kind of inspection in order to find the correct parameter and modify it, no matter if it has been passed as keyword or indexed argument.

Be aware that I slightly changed the tests in order to make it work for me (I "deprecate" ints and require strs). You just need my `check_opp()` function and apply it to wherever you need.

Comment: +1, but I've seen better looking code in brainf*ck :) That is pretty damn ugly!

Comment: @JoelCornett yes, it is :-) But if the `opponent` is sometimes here and sometimes there, you have nearly no other choice...

Comment: The "opponent" is always a keyword argument (or if not, I can make it so)